# Why I get different results using reshape and expand_dims in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Overall, I am writing a RNN model using Tensorflow. I inherit `RNNCell` and customize my own cell. Finally, I use `dynamic_rnn` to build up the entire RNN. The detail is that I want to transform a tensor from shape [n, m] to [n, m, 1]. I use two methods to implement this:

```
tf.reshape(matrix, [n, m, 1]) # the first method
tf.expand_dims(matrix, -1) # the second method
```

What I expect is that using these two methods, I will get totally identical training and prediction results(All the random seeds are fixed). But the results are different. I am really confused.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.reshape` just rearranges the elements, but `tf.expand_dims` adds a dimension to your tensor. Their functions are different.

However, you would expect that due to random initialization, everytime you train the results should be slightly different.

Comment: Thanks! I use session.run to get the results of both `reshape(matrix, [n,m,1])` and `expand_dims(matrix, -1)`, they are totally the same. What do you mean by "Their functions are different"? I set fixed random seeds, so there is no randomness everytime  I run the code.

Comment: So you consistently get the same results with the same input?

Comment: Yes, if I consistently use method 1 (or method 2), I always get the same results, because the random seeds are fixed. But if I switch my code from method 1 to method 2 (vice versa), I get different results.